# Eclipse e4 ViewPart. Не работает глобальный handler Save и SaveAll

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Создана e4view, для которой необходимо реализовать функциональность editor-а в части поддержки команд Save и SaveAll. По туториалам в сети мне понятно, что достаточно реализовать следующий код для этого:

```
    @Inject
      public AbstractView(MDirtyable a_dirtyable)
      {
        Objects.requireNonNull(m_dirtyable);
        m_dirtyable= a_dirtyable;
      }

    @Persist
      public void save()
      {
       // сохранение данных
       ....

         m_dirtyable.setDirty(false);
      }

      // метод вызывается после определенных действий пользователя и изменении каких-либо     данных
     public void markDirty()
     {
         m_dirtyable.setDirty(true);
     }
```

После реализации этого ViewPart стала вести себя следующим образом:
- после определенных действий пользователя на закладке вью стала прорисовываться звездочка(т.е. она становилась "dirty")
- но глобальные кнопки Save и SaveAll остаются недоступными и комбинации клавиш CTRL+S и CTRL+SHIFT+S не работают
- когда закрывают вью появляется окно с предложением сохранить изменения и только когда нажать на OK в этом окне срабатывает метод вью, помеченный @Persist

Что я делаю не так?